# jinfo for java-7-openjdk-amd64

Tags: ubuntu, java

I am trying to check my memory settings currently in use with tomcat via [jinfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jinfo.html) on Ubuntu.

However when running `jinfo -flags <PID>` against the tomcat PID, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo jinfo -flags 14930

Attaching to process ID 14930, please wait...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at sun.tools.jinfo.JInfo.runTool(JInfo.java:97)
    at sun.tools.jinfo.JInfo.main(JInfo.java:71)
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VMVersionMismatchException: Supported versions are 23.25-b01. Target VM is 24.65-b04
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VM.checkVMVersion(VM.java:234)
```

This error suggests that there is version mismatch (`Supported versions are 23.25-b01. Target VM is 24.65-b04`).

The tomcat7 instance is configured with java-7-openjdk-amd64

However, `jinfo` is using java-6-openjdk-amd64

To see if there was an alternative jinfo I could use as part of java-7-openjdk-amd64 I ran the following:

```
$ update-alternatives --get-selections | grep jinfo
jinfo                          auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/jinfo
```

But didn't find anything. I then looked in the bin directory for java-7-openjdk-amd64, but of course found no jinfo there as well.

Does java-7-openjdk-amd64 not ship with jinfo anymore?

The Oracle documentation does state:

> NOTE - This utility is unsupported and may or may not be available in
>   future versions of the JDK

If not, is there an alternative?